# A copy programming on Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

```
2012-07-13 11:26:14.563 -CarParts-Copy[569:403] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[Slant6<0x10d5adab8> init]: cannot init a class object.'
```

I don't know how to fix it.That's the programming on book "Learn Objective-C on the Mac" written by Mark Dalrymple and Scott Knaster.
Programming  13.01-CarParts-Copy.

I have implied successfully but i can't get the correct answer.

The correct answer is

```
2012-07-13 11:30:19.743 -CarParts-Copy[574:403] AllWeatherRadial: 34.0 / 20.0 / 0.0 / 0.0 
2012-07-13 11:30:19.744 -CarParts-Copy[574:403] AllWeatherRadial: 34.0 / 20.0 / 0.0 / 0.0 
2012-07-13 11:30:19.746 -CarParts-Copy[574:403] AllWeatherRadial: 34.0 / 20.0 / 0.0 / 0.0 
2012-07-13 11:30:19.747 -CarParts-Copy[574:403] AllWeatherRadial: 34.0 / 20.0 / 0.0 / 0.0 
2012-07-13 11:30:19.747 -CarParts-Copy[574:403] I am a slant-6.VROOOM!
2012-07-13 11:30:19.743 -CarParts-Copy[574:403] AllWeatherRadial: 34.0 / 20.0 / 0.0 / 0.0 
2012-07-13 11:30:19.744 -CarParts-Copy[574:403] AllWeatherRadial: 34.0 / 20.0 / 0.0 / 0.0 
2012-07-13 11:30:19.746 -CarParts-Copy[574:403] AllWeatherRadial: 34.0 / 20.0 / 0.0 / 0.0 
2012-07-13 11:30:19.747 -CarParts-Copy[574:403] AllWeatherRadial: 34.0 / 20.0 / 0.0 / 0.0 
2012-07-13 11:30:19.747 -CarParts-Copy[574:403] I am a slant-6.VROOOM!
```

That's the programming about copy. It took me such a long time. Thx for the people who answer this question.

Comment: Can you provide us some code examples on the error?

Comment: we need to see the code, preferably the area you think or know is breaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really tell without your code, but it seems like you're calling `init` on a class name, like

```
[SomeObject init];
```

which is trying to `init` a class, giving you the error. To fix this problem, try

```
[[SomeObject alloc] init];
```

which will allocate an instance of a class, and `init` that instead.

Comment: that's my fault by using a wrong init . thx